# Entity Framework 4.1 dynamically retrieve summary for scalar properties from database table column description

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using Entity-Framework 4.1 database-first approach. I have a legacy database which every table column has description. It's very helpful when you watch those description in database diagram.

At the same Entity Framework `DataContext` has a `Summary` property for each scalar value.

I'm wondering is there any way I could load those descriptions from the database and map them to the `Summary` of scalar properties ?

I would appreciate any directions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [How can I make the Entity data model designer use my database column descriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2747788/337294), Vote for the feature at <del>https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/498313/retrieve-the-sql-descriptions-in-entity-framework</del> [See update], Or if you are in a hurry, buy a third party tool at http://huagati.com/dbmltools/.

**Update**: Just found out that ADO.Net team has marked the feature as `Won't fix` in [Their feedback center](https://connect.microsoft.com/data/feedback/details/677956/import-t-sql-description-on-the-edmx-documentation-field). But found a tool that does the work at http://eftsqldocgenerator.codeplex.com/. Haven't tested it though.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion sure, but marking a feature like this as "*Won't fix*" is just plain garbage.