# Can I map a database column description to the DisplayNameAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Entity Framework 4.1 dynamically retrieve summary for scalar properties from database table column description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950917/entity-framework-4-1-dynamically-retrieve-summary-for-scalar-properties-from-dat)

Is it possible to map the Column Description (the extended property `MS_Description` in the database ) to the `DisplayNameAttribute` (the name used by `@Html.DisplayNameFor`) ?

I don't want to use Data Annotations, as I would like the DBA to set the proper column descriptions in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
MvcApplication10.Models.Acesso_Usuario


   <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Senha)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Senha)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Senha)
    </div>
```

If you are using CSHTML He wil set name automatic from DBA, whitout data annotations.