# Get Extended Property in edmx modeling Db

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, extended-properties

I have a database modelling by Entity Framework. I need to read the extended properties of each table through the object context associated to my Db. How can i do?

Thank's in advance

Comment: Look into this Post [How can I make the Entity data model designer use my database column descriptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747788/how-can-i-make-the-entity-data-model-designer-use-my-database-column-description)

Comment: Thank's but i search a so fast solution there isn't?